# how to get bash to redirect command output in multi line format to file

Tags: bash, file, redirect, multiline, output

how do you get bash to redirect output of a command with multiple outputs to a file with multiple lines. Example:

```
rsync --progress -v /source /destination >> file.txt
```

cat file.txt would give:

```
file1 file2 file3
```

when I would like the file to look like the output that's on the terminal or stdout:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: Do you perhaps have a more complete, self-contained example? Your rsync command doesn't output anything close to "file1 file2 file3", it includes progress information and statistics for each transfer.

Comment: Does the rsync output still appear on multiple lines if you pipe it through cat? `rsync --progress -v /source /destination | cat` If not, then rsync is behaving differently depending on whether its output is a terminal so you'd have to use a program like [unbuffer](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) to fool it into thinking it was still writing to a terminal.

Comment: I'm actually using "s3cmd sync" with --no-progress flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to translate spaces to newlines, use `tr`:

```
rsync --progress -v /source /destination | tr ' ' '\012' >> file.txt
```

Comment: It is octal for decimal value 10, e.g. the newline ASCII character.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using a command "s3cmd sync --no-progress /source /dest >> file.txt" piping it through cat worked. Thanks for the help. The "| tr ' ' '/012' >> file.txt" also worked, but it treated every space on the line as a new line. Thanks for the help.